# How to upgrade to newer OpenSSH version on OpenBSD

Tags: upgrade, openssh, openbsd

I'm on OpenBSD 6.8 and am running OpenSSH 8.4. How do I upgrade to OpenSSH 8.6, the newest version? Based off of this page https://www.openssh.com/openbsd.html , I know where to download it from, just not how. Where do I extract the .tar.gz to? Are there other steps besides just restarting sshd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH is part of the OpenBSD base system.  The components of the base system are *never* upgraded individually, but always as part of a full base system upgrade.  It is *possible* (by patching the base system's source code), but you will not get help from official OpenBSD mailing lists for your Frankenstein-system, and I would strongly advice against it.  There is nothing saying that the OpenSSH from the current snapshot would work *at all* with an otherwise stable (not snapshot) OpenBSD system.

Having said that, the page that you link to seems to contain clear instructions on how to install the latest OpenSSH on top of a recent OpenBSD system. I doubt this is a recommended upgrade path though.

In short, if you are using the `-release` or `-stable` branch of OpenBSD, you will get OpenSSH 8.6 when you upgrade your system to the [OpenBSD 6.9](https://www.openbsd.org/69.html) release, which currently is planned in for around May 1, 2021.

If you are extremely eager to get OpenSSH 8.6, you can try the instructions you linked to, but you also have the option to upgrade the system to [a snapshot release](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/current.html) (but it would then be difficult to move the system back on to a stable release after that).

In either case, it is the [`sysupgrade`](https://man.openbsd.org/sysupgrade) utility that is the most convenient to use to upgrade between stable releases, or between snapshots, provided you have a mostly default base system.

Answer (score -1):

In general, this process is called "building from source", and goes like this (assuming you have a working C compiler):

- Download the archive (the `.tar.gz`). Put the file somewhere you can write, and on a filesystem with enough space. In the end, this file is disposable.
- Inspect the archive (`tar tzvf ...`, see `man tar`). Most unpack into a subdirectory. For the few that don't, `mkdir` your own subdirectory, `mv` the `.tar.gz` into it, and `cd` there.
- Unpack the archive (`tar xzvf ...`).
- Read the files with all upper case names (`README*`, `INSTALL`, ... ). They contain complete instructions, and override anything I type after this.
- If there's a `configure` script, run it (`./configure`). `configure` takes many options, see the `INSTALL` file or `./configure -h`. If `configure` succeeds, it will construct a `Makefike`.
- `make` compiles and links what is necessary. It produces an executable that can be tested before installation.
- This is the only step requiring `root` privileges: `sudo make install`. This command copies the executable, `man` pages, run-time necessities, to the "right" places.
- Once `sudo make install` has worked, the whole source directory is redundant, and may be deleted.

Then you can restart `sshd`.

As always, YMMV.

Comment: Note that the user links to a page with clear instructions specifically for use on an OpenBSD systems. Also note that OpenBSD does not use `sudo` by default.  OpenBSD, by default, has one or two C compilers in its base system.